# Appending to array or looping iterable from fixed array

Tags: python, numpy

I have been using this method for Ranges. I can't work out an equivalent method for fixed lists/arrays.

```
# What I've been using & OUTPUT I'm looking for.

degrees = np.arange(10,50,10)
ITER = np.array(degrees)
for i in range( 4): 
    x1 = np.sin(np.radians(ITER))
    y1 = np.cos(np.radians(ITER ))
XY = np.column_stack((np.asarray(x1),np.asarray(y1)))
print(XY)
```

Bad code:

```
# appending to array has seen many failures.  
# appended array always prints empty. must have a false assumption
xy1 = np.array([])
degrees = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
for degree in np.nditer(degrees):
    x1 = np.sin(np.radians(degree))
    y1 = np.cos(np.radians(degree))
    #np.append(xy1,[x1,y1]).reshape(2,1)
    #ugh = np.asarray([x1,y1])
    #a = np.append(xy1,[[x1,y1]],axis =0).reshape(2,-1)
    #a = np.append(xy1,[[x1],[y1]],axis =0)#.reshape(2,-1)
    #np.append(xy1,ugh, axis =0).reshape(2,1)
    #np.append(xy1,ugh, axis =0)
    #a = np.append(xy1,[ugh])
XY = np.column_stack((np.asarray(x1),np.asarray(y1)))
print(xy1)

# OUTPUT should be same as working example above
```

With the benefit of hindsight I would have used lists... But now I wish to use this as learning opportunity.

***Update:*** Answers as provided by [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)

```
# Iterate through Range
degrees = np.arange(10,50,10)
x1 = np.sin(np.radians(degrees))
y1 = np.cos(np.radians(degrees ))
XY = np.column_stack((x1, y1))

# Iterate through fixed list
degrees = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
XY = np.zeros((0,2))
for rad in np.radians(degrees):
    XY = np.append(XY, [[np.sin(rad), np.cos(rad)]], axis=0)
```

My main mistake was the initialization of the array as wrong shape.

```
XY = np.zeros((0,2))
degrees = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
for rads in np.radians(degrees):
    x1 = np.sin(rads)
    y1 = np.cos(rads)
    XY = np.append(XY, [[x1,y1]]).reshape(-1,2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to produce?  What's the end result?

Comment: Don't try to imitate a list append approach with arrays.  There are many ways to get it wrong, and it is slow when it does work.  At the very least read the docs of `np.append` five times until really understand what it does - and look at the `[source]` code.

Comment: You should make an example that is easier to understand for us. It is hard to tell what your expected output is. Also you should avoid appending arrays if it is possible.

Comment: Since you were trying to learn, I probably should have insisted on seeing the errors.  Without the `appends` `xy1` doesn't change at all, and `XY` is just the last `degree` calculation.  The appends have various problems - mostly you don't use the returned array.  But even if you did, you'd run into shape and dimensions mismatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code runs; why are you trying to write something else?

But I think you need to understand the first one better.  Let's run it:

```
In [449]: degrees = np.arange(10,50,10)
     ...: ITER = np.array(degrees)
     ...: for i in range( 4): 
     ...:     x1 = np.sin(np.radians(ITER))
     ...:     y1 = np.cos(np.radians(ITER ))
     ...: XY = np.column_stack((np.asarray(x1),np.asarray(y1)))

In [450]: degrees
Out[450]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])

In [451]: ITER
Out[451]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

`arange` produces an array (READ THE DOCS); so why the extra `np.array(degrees)` call?  It doesn't change any; it just makes a another copy.

```
In [452]: XY
Out[452]: 
array([[0.17364818, 0.98480775],
       [0.34202014, 0.93969262],
       [0.5       , 0.8660254 ],
       [0.64278761, 0.76604444]])
```

`degrees` is (4,) shape; `x1` is as well, and `XY` is (4,2), concatenating two 1d arrays as columns.

Why the iteration for `range(4)`?  Just to make the code run slower by repeating the `sin` calculations?  You do the same thing 4 times, and don't accumulate anything.  It just uses the last run to make `XY`. And `x1` is already an array; why the extra `np.array(x1)` wrapping?

```
In [453]: x1,y1
Out[453]: 
(array([0.17364818, 0.34202014, 0.5       , 0.64278761]),
 array([0.98480775, 0.93969262, 0.8660254 , 0.76604444]))

In [454]: np.sin(np.radians(ITER))
Out[454]: array([0.17364818, 0.34202014, 0.5       , 0.64278761])
```

I don't know whether you are just being careless, or don't understand the basics of Python iteration.

This is all you need:

```
degrees = np.arange(10,50,10)
x1 = np.sin(np.radians(ITER))
y1 = np.cos(np.radians(ITER ))
XY = np.column_stack((x1, y1))
```

### 2nd try

I just noticed you use `np.nditer`.  Why?  If you are going to iterate, use the straight forward

```
 for degree in degress:
       ....
```

`nditer` is not a faster way of iterating; the docs may be misleading in this regard.  It is really only useful as a stepping stone toward writing fancy iterations in `cython`.  The python version is slow - and overly complicated for most users.

As the first code shows, you don't need to iterate to calculate sin/cos for all `degrees`.  But if you must iterate, here's a simple clear version:

```
In [457]: degrees = np.arange(10,50,10)
     ...: x1, y1 = [], []
     ...: for degree in degrees:
     ...:     x1.append(np.sin(np.radians(degree)))
     ...:     y1.append(np.cos(np.radians(degree)))
     ...: XY = np.column_stack((np.array(x1), np.array(y1)))

In [458]: x1
Out[458]: 
[0.17364817766693033,
 0.3420201433256687,
 0.49999999999999994,
 0.6427876096865393]
```

`x1`,`y1` are lists; list append is relatively fast, and simple.  `np.append` is slow and hard to use correctly.  Don't use it (like `nditer` it needs a stronger disclaimer, and maybe even removal).

Here's a version of iteration with `np.append` that works; I don't recommend it, but it illustrates how `np.append` might work:

```
 In [461]: degrees = np.arange(10,50,10)
 ...: XY = np.zeros((0,2))
 ...: for rad in np.radians(degrees):
 ...:     XY = np.append(XY, [[np.sin(rad), np.cos(rad)]], axis=0)
```

I do just one `np.radians` conversion.  No need to repeat or do it in the iteration.

I initial `XY` as a (0,2) array - and I add a (1,2) array to it at each iteration.  `np.append` with axis is just

```
  XY = np.concatenate((XY, [[np.sin...]]), axis=0)
```

Your failed tries have various problems.  `np.array([])` has shape (0,). You can't join a (2,) to that with `axis`).  `np.append` returns a new array; it does not work in-place.  None of your tries changes `xy1`.

Looking more at that second block of code, I get the impression that you are just being careless. You mix `xy1`, `x1`, `y1`, `a`, `XY` without paying attention to how they might, or might not, be related.